# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition - Unable to identify the root cause

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, vb.net-2010

Getting error on

> cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

My Current Code

```
Using con As New SqlConnection(sConString)
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand(
        "INSERT INTO MC_Entry VALUES(" &
        "@0,@1, @2, @3, @4, @5,@6,@7,@8,@9,@10,@11,@12,@13,@14,@15,@16,@17," &
        "@18, @19, @20, @21, @22,@23,@24,@25,@26,@27,@28,@29,@30,@31,@32,@33,@34," &
        "@35, @36, @37, @38, @39,@40,@50,@51,@52,@53,@54)", con)

        For MyIncremental = 0 To 54
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & MyIncremental, vValues(MyIncremental))
        Next MyIncremental

        'Debug.Print(UBound(vValues))
        'Debug.Print(LBound(vValues))
        'Debug.Print(Join(vValues, vbTab))


        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
    End Using
End Using
```

Lowerbound Value of vValues = 0
and
Upperbound Value of vValues = 54

I am having 55 columns in my SQL server table with NO Incremental field and every field can accept Null value.

Not sure why I am getting this error since everything seems to be Okay...

> **Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.**

Any suggestions?

**Based on the answer post, I finally made it in loop so that I will  not miss the necessary strings in future.**

```
For i = 0 To 54
    ReDim Preserve sfields(0 To i)
    sfields(i) = "@" & i
Next

sConcat = Join(sfields, ",")

Using con As New SqlConnection(sConString)
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MC_Entry VALUES(" & sConcat & ")", con)

        For i = 0 To 54
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" & i, vValues(i))
        Next i

        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Are you missed `@41` to `@49` values?

Comment: You're right... Don't know how I missed that part.  Now it's working fine.

Comment: I made it in loop to avoid the missing string issue in future.  Updated the same in my Initial Post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally you have 55 columns in the table and you are missing the parameters from `@41` to `@49`, that causing the error.

Include like below will solve your problem

```
"INSERT INTO MC_Entry VALUES(" &
"@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6, @7, @8, @9, @10, @11, @12, @13, @14, @15, @16, @17," &
"@18, @19, @20, @21, @22, @23, @24, @25, @26, @27, @28, @29, @30, @31, @32, @33," &
"@34, @35, @36, @37, @38, @39, @40, @41, @42, @43, @44, @45, @46, @47, @48, @49," &
"@50, @51, @52, @53, @54)", con)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick solution and review :)

Comment: @Sixthsense Glad to help, it happens to me too if I'm focusing on particular task with out break. Take a break. Cheers :)

Comment: True.  Currently working with multiple project environment which may be the cause.